# camel producertemplate only sending 2 http requests at a time

Tags: apache-camel, connection-pooling, httpconnection

I'm using the Camel's ProducerTemplate to make http calls like below.

```
@Produce
private ProducerTemplate producer;

producer.requestBodyAndHeaders(url, requestString, headers,
                    String.class);
```

In my application, I'm using this to call another time taking rest api multiple times for a batch job. But from the access logs of the other server, I found that the server is getting only 2 requests at a time.
Once, it processes these two, it was getting another 2 requests.

Looks like something to do with the connection pooling of Camel's producerTemplate. Is it defaulting to 2 connections?

How can I change this configuration?

Comment: Doubt it is the pooling. Does the log state that the producer is actually being called twice?

Comment: Depends on the http component you use such as camel-http. That client has a default of max 2 connection per host, which you need to increase.

Comment: Thanks Claus. I found in the below link how to change the max connections: Under the section 'Setting MaxConnectionsPerHost'. Is that how it works? http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/http.html

Comment: Verified that the example provided in the above link is working